# Animation Not Rendering all the Way Through

Tags: rendering, camera

I have several cameras that each take over at some point during the animation. While rendering, the last camera doesn't render; only the first one does.

[image]

I thought maybe it would be because I can only have a limited number of cameras, so to make a test, I erased the first. However, the last one still does not work.

I am using the *VSE* for post processing.

Comment: Please supply a blend file.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood thanks for answering, and solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OP's answer to the question that was originally an edit.**

I solved the problem! I'll leave it here if anyone needs the help.

The problem was that in the *VSE*, the scene I used initially lasted only 700 frames. Later, I added more animation to the scene, but did not lengthen the *VSE Scene* strip.

[image]